# Deleting Bot generated messages in DMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I started not a while ago with discord.js and was working on a command handler - on commands in general.
I realised that my bot could also reply on DMs, so I tried this:

```js
if (!msg.guild) {

msg.channel.send("I am not answering to to DMs, please respect that!");

}
```

I somehow bugged and replied to me with like 10 messages and it would go on if I hadn't stopped the bot.

Now I decided I don't want the bot even to reply to a dm, it should just ignore it, but now I have like 10/20 messages from him I can't get rid of.
Can anyone send me one line of code where I can manually delete a single message? I would like to copy the ID of every message he wrote to me that's not the problem.

Comment: This isn't possible AFAIK. Other people had similar issues, since it's not a public channel the bot can't delete messages.

Comment: It is possible, as long as the DM channel is between the bot and someone else, the bot can only delete its own messages.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const User = client.users.cache.get("UserId") // Your Discord ID.
const MessageId = "ID"; // The ID of the message you want to delete.

User.dmChannel.messages.fetch(MessageId).then(m => m.delete()) // Fecthing the message and then deleting it.
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dmChannel' of undefined

Comment: Okay I just found out when I try to console.log(User), it says undefined

Comment: Make sure the UserId is correct and you are using Discord JS v12.

Comment: using "^12.2.0" and the ID (my own ID, not the bot's one) I copied several times

Comment: okay so I found one problem, it was that those commands were executed before the bot even started properly, I moved the code now in my client.on("message"...)
But now it says:
User.dmChannel.messages.fetch(MessageId).then(m => m.delete());
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of null

Comment: dmChannel is null if the bot hasn't sent you any messages.

Comment: :/ nvm ty anyway! It's not that big of a deal, just wanted to know if I can delete it

Answer (score 0):

This might be long, but I noticed this question and already have a function in my bot to delete its DMs to a user....

deleteDMs( user, resultsChannel ) {

```
this.#client.users.fetch( user.id )
.then( u => {

    u.createDM()
    .then( dmchannel => { 
        dmchannel.messages.fetch( { limit: 100 } )
        .then( messages => {

            let c = messages.size;
            messages = messages.filter( m => { return m.author.id === this.#client.user.id } );

            if( c !== messages.size ){

                resultsChannel.send( `No can do - ${u.toString()} must delete DMs to ${this.toString()}` +
                `  before ${this.toString()} can delete my DMs to ${u.toString()}. (Discord API quirk.)` );

            }else{

                c = messages.size;
                resultsChannel.send( `Deleting ${c} DMs.` );

                messages.forEach( msg => {

                    msg.delete()
                    .then( () => {

                        c --;
                        if( c === 0 ) resultsChannel.send( 'DMs deleted successfully.');

                    } ).catch( err => { resultsChannel.send( `Error occurred while deleting DMs.\n${err}` ) } );

                } );//end messages.forEach

            }//end if( c !===

        } ).catch( err => { resultsChannel.send( `Error occurred while fetching DMs.\n${err}` ) } );

    } ).catch( err => { resultsChannel.send( `Error occurred while resolving DM channel.\n${err}` ) } );

} ).catch( err => { resultsChannel.send( `Error occurred while fetching user.\n${err}` ) } );
```

}//end deleteDMs

Comment: It deletes DMs from client (bot) to specified user.  One caveat is that the user must first delete all their DMs to the bot - just a discord API quirk.